# Why is stdio.h not included in C?

Tags: c

Why do other languages like java have a print function included and C doesn't? What is the reason for stdio.h not being included in the language?

Stdio.h is almost included in every C file so why doesn't the language provide the stdio.h functionalities?

Comment: libc (which provides implementations for C language) is writtenin C. imagine if they included `stdio.h` before writing it

Comment: The system calls `read()` and `write()` (which all I/O functions will ultimately invoke in machine code) do not require `stdio.h`, but instead require `unistd.h`. You can do all I/O using system calls (somewhat cumbersome) without the convenience of stream based I/O functions.

Comment: For freestanding environments (standalone systems) ([§5.1.2.1 Freestanding environments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.1) and [§4 Conformance](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p6)), the C standard only requires that these headers are provided (and `<stdio.h>` is not in the list):  `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`.  So, demanding that C always include `<stdio.h>` would invalidate a whole class of environments where standard C can currently exist (without `<stdio.h>`).

Comment: The language standard does provide `stdio.h`, see [C18 Draft 7.21 - Input/output<stdio.h>](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf) It is provided for all **hosted** implementations (systems that have an OS). For **freestanding** systems - whether `stdio.h` is provided is *implementation defined*.

Comment: If it was automatically included it becomes a bit of a slippery slope argument. If stdio then why not stdlib? Why not string? C gives you a lot of flexibility to use what you need and very little else at the expense of having to know where to get what you need.

Comment: "Stdio.h is almost included in every C file" --> Your survey is too narrow.

Answer (score 6):

Because not every C implementation (program) uses stdio.